# Combine vis-network and vis-timeline on same page

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I'm trying to use the network and timeline package on the same page (like I did when using the old 4.21 version, and it works there), but I can't get it to work. It's throwing an error (dataset or array expected), when I provide the vis-datasets to the network. If I remove the load of the js for the timeline in the header, it works - but then I don't have a timeline.

So it looks like loading the package for the timeline is interfering with the vis-datasets definitions.
Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that I need to use the DIST from [vis-charts](https://github.com/visjs/vis-charts) to have this working.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify this is a known bug we're actively working to solve. It will work as you'd expect eventually. See https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/pull/85 for more information. In the mean time as you found out yourself use vis-charts.